How to Restrict PowerShell SDK to Limit Script Access to Specific Callback Methods in a C# Application?
In my C# application I want to use the PowerShell SDK to allow user-provided PS scripts to interact with limited parts of the application through callbacks. I want to restrict what these scripts can do, ideally allowing only specific methods to be called on a provided callback interface, without giving full access to system resources or sensitive .NET types.
Here’s a simplified code example:
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateRestricted(SessionCapabilities.Language);
iss.LanguageMode = PSLanguageMode.FullLanguage;  // ConstrainedLanguage would inhibit the callbacks

// Add specific cmdlets, for example
iss.Commands.Add(new SessionStateCmdletEntry("New-Object", typeof(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand), ""));
iss.Commands.Add(new SessionStateCmdletEntry("Select-Object", typeof(Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SelectObjectCommand), ""));

// Create runspace
using var rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(iss);
rs.Open();

// Provide a limited callback object
IMySafeCallbacks callbacks = new MySafeCallbacks();
rs.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("callbacks", callbacks);

// Run the PowerShell script
using var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Runspace = rs;
ps.AddScript(@"$callbacks.LogMessage('Hello from script');");
var results = ps.Invoke();

Requirements:

Restrict Access: Scripts should only be able to call specific
methods on the IMySafeCallbacks interface, with no access to other
.NET types or system resources.
Prevent Unauthorized Access: Avoid exposing any ability for the
script to access system resources (like read/write files) or create arbitrary objects.

Challenges:

If I use PSLanguageMode.ConstrainedLanguage, the script fails when
invoking methods on the callback interface due to limited .NET type
support.
In PSLanguageMode.FullLanguage, there’s no straightforward way to
prevent access to file system operations or arbitrary .NET object
creation through methods like New-Object or [System.IO.File].

Question:
How can I configure the PowerShell runspace to limit the available cmdlets and methods strictly to those defined in my IMySafeCallbacks interface? Is there a way to allow only specific methods from my application to be called while blocking access to sensitive system operations? Or a way to allow calling into IMySafeCallbacks even in PSLanguageMode.ConstrainedLanguage?
Any guidance or example code on how to securely limit PowerShell SDK in this scenario would be greatly appreciated!

Use ConstrainedLanguage mode, but add a function to the session state that proxies the callbacks - then you can control input with parameter validation, calling user just does Invoke-CallBack -Stub LogMessage -Arguments "Hello from script!"

Thanks for the suggestion! My concern is that script authors are used to direct method calls, so needing to adapt to Invoke-Callback -Stub LogMessage -Arguments 'Hello' might feel cumbersome for them. Any ideas for keeping the direct syntax while still applying ConstrainedLanguage restrictions?

Why choose PowerShell as a deployment target if the audience is... not familiar with PowerShell? Might as well just write a simple CLI/REPL in C# and call it a day then :)

That's a good point, but PowerShell provides some flexibility to evaluate the results of the callbacks that I might want to keep.

If you want PowerShell server-side but restricting user input, then you might want to have a look at PowerShell JEA - same problem though, you'd be exposing commands to the users rather than .NET objects directly

From the requirements you've put forth, have you looked at/considered WCF + PowerShell? This would be far easier to control access and limit what can be run on the remote end.
I have an example of how to do this, both in the PowerShell commandlet and the WCF Service Activity side.

Thank you for the suggestion. WCF certainly has strong capabilities for controlled access. That said, since WCF is now considered more of a legacy technology, especially with Microsoft’s focus shifting toward newer options, I'm hesitant to use it in a new solution.

While that's true (re: Microsoft supporting WCF in .NET Framework), it was ported to .NET Core as CoreWCF and is claimed as supported on .NET8.0.
